# Prometheus query to get just latest data for every day, (Max timestamp every day)

Tags: counter, prometheus, grafana, metrics, promql

I have a PromQL query that returns data for past **n** days with interval of 10 minutes,
is there any way I create a report that contains just **n** entry and each entry is the last value of the day?
my current query is like:
sum(increase(mymetric[1d]))
the output data is like:

```
"Time","sum(increase(mymetric[1d]))"
2022-02-22 15:00:00,89637
2022-02-22 15:10:00,89715
2022-02-22 15:20:00,89711
2022-02-22 15:30:00,89751
2022-02-22 15:40:00,89737
2022-02-22 15:50:00,89774
2022-02-22 16:00:00,89811
...
...

2022-03-22 15:00:00,89671
```

What I need is an output like:

```
2022-02-22 00:00:00,89637
2022-02-23 00:00:00,89715
2022-02-24 00:00:00,89711
2022-02-25 00:00:00,89751
...
2022-03-22 00:00:00,89737
```

p.s. This query is something like a counter,

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution, I'm using Grafana for reporting, In Grafana I defined ***Min Step*** to ***1d*** and the final report is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `max_over_time(metric{}[24h])` but I'm not sure how to align it with the beginning of the day (or some other time of the day)